# VirtualBox VM's on a USB?

Tags: virtualbox, usb-flash-drive

I need to use several different VM's, using Oracle VirtualBox. Unfortunately, my laptop has a 100Gb SSD, so I was thinking of hosting them on an external USB flash drive.

My question is, would a USB 3.0 flash drive make a world of difference in speed when using a VM, or would a USB 2.0 suffice?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the flash drive. If the flash drive is capable of 500kb/s it won't matter if you're on USB 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your use.  If you are just booting and then not hitting the disk very much, you would not be likely to have any problems.

If you are looking at using the VM often or with high disk activity, a drive (not necessarily 3.0) with high throughput would increase your overall performance to that which would rival most laptop hard disks (60 MB/s transfer).  A high performance USB 3.0 flash drive can even get up into SSD range (300 MB/s read).